# how many possible of mix two random orders together

Tags: algorithm

If i  make  26 English letters random  order , I  will  get  26!  possibles ,

and  if I  make number  0  to  9  random  order , I  will  get 10!  possibles

final  if  I  want  mix above two together ,also  random  order , mean it  maybe  looks  like  :

```
c23f7............k5
```

Does  it  exist  one algorithms to calculate how  many  possibles ?  especially base on  the  two  numbers  10! and  26!

Comment: Are you allowed duplicate numbers / letters? How long is the string? Or do you want to exhaust *all* letters and numbers? Also, as this question is not related to programming, but specifically to math, this question may be more suitable for the [**Math StackExchange**](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: hi , no duplicate numbers / letters, exhaust all letters and numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(10+26)!**

There are 10+26 possibilities for the first cipher, and for the next one, without repetition, 35, then 34 and so on. So for the same reason, you can order 10 elements in 10! ways without repetition, it is 36! for 36 elements.

Comment: seems  you  are right ,  so it looks like A! + B! = (A+B)!

Comment: @yangl it is definitely wrong. just calculate 2! + 3! and 5!

Comment: Hi Aguinore , I  mean possibles , just like fact overloaded operator “+”